# Link to primary and secondary data sources in Tableau

Tags: graph, visualization, tableau-api

I’m trying to create a dashboard filter in Tableau. All but one of my graphs have the same primary data source A. The filter will affect all these graphs as intended. However I have one sheet where the primary data source is B, and the secondary data source is A. I can’t get this particular graph to link to the quick filter I’ve created. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to filter multiple data sources from a single user control is to use a parameter along with calculated fields in each data source that reference the parameter setting. The calculated fields can then be put on the filter shelf for the appropriate worksheets.

This solution doesn't fit every circumstance.

Parameters can only have a single value, and the list of arbitrary values must either be defined statically in the workbook or allow the user to enter an arbitrary value. You can't dynamically lookup the list of legal parameter values in a database table (although you can use a field to populate the list initially).

Parameters are independent of any data source.

So if these restrictions don't hamper your use case, then you can have one parameter control on a dashboard that influences the filters applied to many worksheets. The simplest calculated field used for filtering could just say `[My_Field] = [My_Parameter]`. You can allow extend this idea to define parameter values that reference multiple choices like: "A", "B", "A and B" and then adjust your calculated fields accordingly. At some point, this approach gets unwieldy.

Another approach is use a worksheet as a filter, by displaying marks for each option, and then using filter actions to use the selected marks to filter other worksheets. This approach allows multiple selection, and dynamically loading choices from a database table.